# Draw a basic triangle with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am triyng to learn three.js I want to dra a basic triangle however my codes do not work.

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 10;


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices= [new THREE.Vector3(2,1,0), new THREE.Vector3(1,3,0), new THREE.Vector3(3,4,0)]; 
geometry.faces = [new THREE.Face3(0,1,2)];
var mesh= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 }) );
scene.add(mesh);


renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Where i am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful with the order in which you add the vertices to the face. If the order follows a clockwise order, the normal vector of the surface will point down. And since your camera looks from above, you won't see the triangle. If the order is counterclockwise, the normal will point towards your camera.

It will work if you change:
`geometry.faces = [new THREE.Face3(0,1,2)];`

To:
`geometry.faces = [new THREE.Face3(1,0,2)];`

You can also use the argument side, which applies it to both sides of the face.
`new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide };`

Answer (score 11):

**With Faces**

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(30, 0, 0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(30, 30, 0);
var triangle = new THREE.Triangle(v1, v2, v3);
var normal = triangle.normal();
geom.vertices.push(triangle.a);
geom.vertices.push(triangle.b);
geom.vertices.push(triangle.c);
geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2, normal));
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(mesh);
```

**Just Outline**

```
 var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-30, 2, 2));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(2, 30, 2));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(30, 2, 2));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-30, 2, 2));

var line = new THREE.Line(
  geometry,
  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 })
);
scene.add(line);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

It's funny how hard was to find an updated answer, since `Geometry` was deprecated in recent versions of Three.js the way I found to draw a plane triangle is with `Shape` primitive.

```
const shape = new THREE.Shape();

const x = 0;
const y = 0;

shape.moveTo(x - 2, y - 2);
shape.lineTo(x + 2, y - 2);
shape.lineTo(x, y + 2);

const TriangleGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
```

based on https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=ShapeGeometry#api/en/geometries/ShapeGeometry

Answer (score 2):

Answer for 2023. Also works for 3D vertex coordinates.

```
let vertices = new Float32Array([
    -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,    // vertex 1
    1.0, -1.0, 1.0,     // vertex 2
    1.0, 1.0, 1.0,      // vertex 3
]);

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'red' }
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh)
```

r150